# Way to take screenshot of a pane in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, window, panel, screenshot

In our project, before we do a check in to VSS, we need to take screen-shot of the check-in file list and store in a folder with date and time.

Is there anyway to take screen-shot of the whole page inside visual studio?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Craig said, Alt + PrintScreen is definitely the right way to capture a selected window.  However, the problem is that if the list of files to commit is too long, you won't get everything.  I personally use SnagIt to do screen captures of things that require scrolling.  It is intelligent enough to capture everything that's off of the window as well.

Comment: I believe they have special pricing in a 5 pack, plus each license is allowed on a desktop and laptop, so it's quite a good deal even for small companies.

Comment: Hi Matsumoto,

Thanks for the reply. I use Alt+PrintScreen in most of the scnerious but I face issue when the list of files is long. May be I need to buy SnagIt to use in our project.

Comment: It's well worth the $50, and you'll find uses for it beyond scrolling capture.  I like quickly capturing screenshots into its library, and then being able to add tags as well.

Comment: "Faststone Capture" is very light-weight and works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Alt + Printscreen button i believe,
alt will let you take a snapshot of the selected window.
Then of course you need to paste it into a paint program...